# Error: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request, During Google Token Access

Tags: c#, google-app-engine, google-oauth

I am able to get "code" from google during user authentication process. I am getting error when trying to get access token.

My Request Url is [this](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?code=4/WOc00WJkiEhptrUdddELTk59Yd0W6ZYN.dd-sT2ZLcdbTHz03rfwI&client_id=6336697d50818-fkurmcofdcgrpf9lp7u3j5naei5.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=y1sXMlydweALR6mdNC5H8ep&redirect_uri=http://www.mypmutestapp.com:80/OAuthVerifier.aspx&grant_type=authorization_code)

My Code for Fetch response

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = requestMethod;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = 0;
WebResponse responseData = request.GetResponse();
```

Geting Exception at `GetResponse()` :

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

I am not able to figure out what I am missing in code. Please help me out here

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've gotten past the first step, and now have an authorization code that you are trying to swap for an access token.

Make sure the request is a POST and make sure that all parameters are in the body of the request, and not in the query string portion. Since it looks like you're in C#, see [Google Analytics API - Retrieve refresh token with OAuth2 & ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070358/google-analytics-api-retrieve-refresh-token-with-oauth2-asp-net/17076419) for what looks like the same issue and resolution.

Finally, please reset your client secret since you included that in the URL that's in your question above. This can be done via the API Console: https://code.google.com/apis/console/